# How to properly update an array inside a react hook state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, state

i've been trying to update the object inside an array that respresents a react state, the object should be updated when the value of an input is changed, I could find a way myself to update it, but i'm not sure enough that it is the proper way to do it because when i open the react dev tools and go to the components tab and click the component that i'm working on, the state doesn't update immidiatly when typing in the input, and in order to see the change i have to click on another component in the dev tool and then go back to the first component and the change is done.

So I'm basically asking if the way i used to update the state is correct and to get some suggestions about better ways to do it so it updates instantly. Thanks

here is the code

the state:

```js
const [items, setItems] = useState([{ name: "", quantity: "", unit: "" }]);
```

the change handling function (the function that updates the state):

```js
const nameChange = (e, i) => {
  const newItems = items;
  newItems[i].name = e.target.value;
  setItems(newItems);
  console.log(items);
};
```

the inputs:

```js
{
  items.map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={i} className={`mt3 ${classes.root}`}>
        <TextField
          onChange={e => nameChange(e, i)}
          style={{ width: "30%" }}
          id="standard-basic"
          label="Item name"
        />
        <TextField
          style={{ width: "25%" }}
          id="standard-basic"
          label="quantity"
        />
        <TextField
          style={{ width: "10%" }}
          id="standard-basic"
          label="Unit"
        />
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```js
    const [items, setItems] = React.useState({
        name: '',
        quantity: '',
        unit: ''
    });
    const handleChange = prop => event => {
        setItems({ ...items, [prop]: event.target.value });
    };
```

on your TextFields:

```js
    <TextField onChange={handleChange('name')}/>
    <TextField onChange={handleChange('quantity')}/>
```

**Update**: if items is an array:

```js
    const updateItem = (prop, event, index) => {
        const old = items[index];
        const updated = { ...old, [prop]: event.target.value }
        const clone = [...items];
        clone[index] = updated;
        setItems(clone);
    }
```

on your TextFields:

```js
{items.map((item, i) => (
    <div key={i}>
        <TextField onChange={e => updateItem('name', e, i)}/>
        <TextField onChange={e => updateItem('quantity', e, i)}/>
        <TextField onChange={e => updateItem('unit', e, i)}/>
    </div>
))}
```

Comment: items should be an array like in the question bcs i use it to render some inputs by iterating through it, so this one didn't work, you may revise it again :(

Comment: I updated the answer to your case, the main idea is to set the state to the new object, is it work for you?

Comment: and it worked! thanks dude, now i have another problem (different than this) I've added a button when clicked it should delete its parent div (div key='{i} ></div>) so basically i would pass i as a parameter to the deleting function but couldnt find any way to delete the right object from the items array, whenever i try it does something different like deleting all the items under the clicked button or smth else, if you'd like to help me i'll ask the question and send u the link

Comment: show me the button and your delete function maybe I can give you the proper way to do, let's make a question with your new code :D

Comment: here is the link for the question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60977463/how-to-delete-objects-from-react-state-hook-array-with-a-button-click

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue when state is object. I used redux and mapStateToProps and I can't listen the property in object change cause react can not check deeper.
Solution: follow code:

```
// in reducer file
 case 'SAVE_SERVICE_STATE': {
      return {
        ...state,
        service: {...payload},
        loading: false,
      };
    } 

//listen service state change
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.serviceState) {
      // do something
    }
  }, [props.serviceState]);
```

hope can help someone.