# How to delete objects from react state hook array with a button click

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a button that deleted an object from an array (which is the state) depending on the passed index, I've tried alot but none of my ways worked :( , so this is the code and hope i can find someone to help:

state:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([{ name: "", quantity: "", unit: "" }]);
```

deleting function:

```
const deleteItem = (i) => {
    const newItems = [...items]
    newItems.splice(i, 1)
    setItems(newItems)
}
```

jsx elements:

```
    {
        items.map((item, i) => {
            return (
                <div key={i} className={`mt3 item-input-wrapper`}>
                    <div>some other els here</div>
                    <button onClick={() => deleteItem(i)} >delete item</button>
                </div>
            )
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it with `filter`:

```
const deleteItem = (i) => {
  setItems(currentItems => currentItems.filter((item, index) => index !== i));
}
```

Altho you'd probably use smth more constant for accessing an item, like an id.

Comment: didn't work, it deletes the last object in that array instead but not the wanted index